# how do I add direction to shadow cast by md-whiteframe in angular-material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying to add shadow to my website footer using md-whiteframe directive in angular material but the direction of shadow is such that it is not visible for footer.

How can I do that ?

I know how to do that using CSS (box-shadow) but i was looking if there is any way using which i can provide direction to shadow..

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't an Angular Material way of doing it, probably because goes against Material design best practice.

Comment: And why is it against material practice? If i have a fixed header and footer, it feels like both should have shadow..